# Error While run react-native run-ios. Error: Cannot find module 'metro-config'

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I am running React-native Project by terminal using react-native run-is command. I want to run it in simulator. first I run npm install ,then react-native run-ios. It showing error

> Error: Cannot find module 'metro-config'
>   Require stack:
>   - /Users/tribond/Projects/JustHelper/justhelper2/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/util/Config.js
>   - /Users/tribond/Projects/JustHelper/justhelper2/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/core/index.js
>   - /Users/tribond/Projects/JustHelper/justhelper2/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cliEntry.js
>   - /Users/tribond/Projects/JustHelper/justhelper2/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js
>   - /Users/tribond/Projects/JustHelper/justhelper2/node_modules/react-native/cli.js
>   - /usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-native-cli/index.js

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You seem to have no `Metro-config` module installed. Install this module.

```
npm i metro-config --save-dev
```

Comment: Now I am getting other issue React Native CLI uses autolinking for native dependencies, but the following modules are linked manually.

Comment: This is not a module used through a link.  Please refer https://facebook.github.io/metro/docs/en/configuration

Comment: This doesn't fix the problem for me. Any other alternatives?

Comment: @Carlo use npm install @react-native/metro-config --save-dev instead

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Add metro-config.js to your root project folder and add the following

```
const {getDefaultConfig, mergeConfig} = require('@react-native/metro- 
config');
const config = {};
module.exports = mergeConfig(getDefaultConfig(__dirname), config);
```

Answer (score 0):

> Latest React Native

As per the latest `react-native` documentation, you must update your dev dependencies for metro config.

I have migrated to `react-native to 72.4` using [Update Helper](https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/?from=0.70.5&to=0.72.4), Please follow the guidelines and file change log strictly to avoid any misses

```
"devDependencies": {
  ...,
  "@react-native/metro-config": "^0.72.11",

 }
```

> Older version of react-native

Check your deve dependency for `metro-config`

```
npm i metro-config --save-dev
```